# Redesigning website: how to get rid of framesets and how to go further?

Tags: frameset, frameset-iframe

I am trying to redesign my website, because it has a frameset, that is annoying. It annoys me because I can't see a *dropdown menu* and a *autocomplete suggestion* because of it (it overlaps it). So now, I want to get rid of this frameset, but I have frames that are very useful. So my question is: how can I get rid of the frameset, without changing the lay-out of my website? With what do I have to replace it?

```
<frameset id="f" border="0" rows="50,*">
<frame scrolling="no" noresize="" src="home.php?process=top" name="bar">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</frame>
<frameset cols="250,*">
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to admit that framesets were not working. Well, I got rid of it because there was no other way out. That simple; don't use it.